# Upload file in S3 using boto3 with Dynamic Foldername

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have 4 S3 buckets : 
SourceBucket\folder1\file1 and DestinationBucket1-folder1,
SourceBucket\folder2\file1 and DestinationBucket2-folder2.
When I upload the folders, I would like the code to check for folder 
'DestinationBucket1-folder1' if it exists and then upload the folder1 and files underneath that folder.

I am struggling with S3 KEY. How can I parse S3 KEY and check if the specifice folder exist and  then upload the first folder under SourceBucket?

Answer (score 0):

The below code creates the folder if not present and uploads the file:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name='us-east-2', aws_access_key_id=access_id, aws_secret_access_key=access_key)
s3.meta.client.upload_file(filePath, backet-name, str(foldername) + "/" + str(sub-foldername) + "/" + filename)
```

Comment: Thanks Yajana. The 'DestinationBucket' + "-" str (foldername) is throwning regex error                                                                                                                                                                                  if s3.lookup(DestinationBucket1-folder1) is None:
    bucket=s3.create_bucket(DestinationBucket1-folder1) # Bucket Don't Exist
else:
    bucket = s3.get_bucket(DestinationBucket1-folder1) #Bucket Exist

Comment: Is it possible for you to give a sample of your code